# Pull Focus in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, camera, focus, pull, avcapturedevice

How to implement the camera  pull focus functionality for `AVCaptureDevice`?

Pull Focus - Suppose there are two objects in the picture one should be point of attention and other will be blurred.